# Disable caching of content in firefox offline mode

Tags: firefox, caching, bfcache

I am working on a web application which has user management in place. I find a concerning issue in firefox related to Work Offline. Following are the steps describing the scenario:

1. User logs in to the application
2. User performs some action and logs out of the application
3. If the user now enables Work Offline mode in firefox, he/she can use browser back to access the last page. However, this page is supposed to be secure.

In my opinion this is a data security issue as any other user can apply this technique to fetch valuable information of the last user.

I have used cache control headers to communicate to the browser that HTML content should not be cached. Following are the response headers used:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 05 May 2015 10:39:30 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.9 (Unix) OpenSSL/0.9.8za
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Expires: Wed, 31 Dec 1969 23:59:59 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Language: en
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

I have used

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Expires: Wed, 31 Dec 1969 23:59:59 GMT
```

I have noted this vulnerability in applications like Facebook. Is this resolvable? Thank you.

Comment: He @Vaibhav have you found any work around this?

Comment: I haven't found any work around for this.